# Alternatives to Leibnitz notation for differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have problems with learning $\frac{dy}{dx}$, etc. notation because of objections that this isn't actually a derivative. Is there an alternative notation with full inherent correctness? Cauchy notation isn't that flexible as Leibnitz's.

Comment: "...this isn't actually a derivative." In what sense?

Comment: If you want to use $dy=f(x+dx)-f(x)$ and $f'(x)={}^°\!\!\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$, then look up non-standard analysis. Robinson is pretty popular, I think the "radically elementary" treatment by Nelson is nicer, but then there are people that don't like NSA at all...

Comment: @LutzL: I watched youtube video on NSA (the only one meaningful) and it's like rock fell of my chest. Finally, one can feed his mind with something defined, clean, it's a journey to truth. If you have any more clues on NSA then they are welcome. I'm looking for good sources to start learning

Comment: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/rept.pdf, it starts at a rather elementary level, but moves fast towards stochastic processes. The books cited in the wikipedia page on NSA, if you can find them, are also a nice source. Skip over all talk about ultrafilters, they are important, as important as Dedekind cuts for real numbers, but who calculates with cuts?

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{df}{dx}$ is a perfectly valid notation for the derivative.  And it has a few benefits that are pretty nice:

1. It tells you exactly which variable you're differentiating wrt.
2. It reminds you of the definition of the derivative: $\frac{df}{dx} = \lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$ and thus that for small $\Delta x$, $\frac{df}{dx}\approx \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$.
3. It makes it easy to remember that the units of the derivative are $\dfrac{\text{units of $f$}}{\text{units of $x$}}$.

That said, there are several alternatives including:

$$Df,\quad D_xf,\quad df,\quad \dot f,\quad f',\quad f^{(1)},\quad f_x$$

As long as your audience is clear about what you mean by a given notation, you can use whichever you like.